# Software(online/offline) to draw graph theory graphs

Tags: graph-theory

I need a software that can draw graph by taking number of vertices , type of label and edges in the format (x y) as input
eg:

```
Input is

Vertices : 4
Labels:1,2,3,4
Edges
1 2
2 3
2 4
3 1
```

Are there any such? I have graphs in this form with almost 100 edges...it will take quite long to draw them..

Comment: If you're familiar with Latex, then it isn't very hard to draw small graphs with tikz.  You could do larger if they graph has enough structure, but this requires more know-how

Comment: Well is there something that's without some know-how...I just want to get the work done as fast as possible...no time to learn anew :(

Comment: Sage should be able to do it.  Try the show command in the [graphs](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/graphs/sage/graphs/graph.html) section.

Comment: You can do this in [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1-%3E2%2C+2-%3E3%2C+2-%3E4%2C+3-%3E1).

Comment: I think that might do the trick...but it shows 1->2 etc ...does that mean directed graph? is it possible to change the separator from -> to something else?

Comment: I did'nt work out! it seems you have to pay for larger inputs ...

Comment: If you are familiar with $\LaTeX$, you can use the [graphtex](http://www.freewebs.com/gervacio/graphtexanintroduction.htm) package by Severino Gervacio.  (Note that there is more than one package called graphtex; the one I'm referring to is the one found in the link.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grand-daddy of them softwares to create graphs is [Graphviz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphviz), dating back to at least the mid 90s. If you don't want to install the software on your computer, there are several online ports that runs in your browser, e.g. [this one](http://hughesbennett.co.uk/Graphviz) or [this one](http://www.webgraphviz.com/).

The main language used is [Dot](http://www.graphviz.org/Documentation.php) in which you specify the vertices and edges similar to what you incorporated in your question statement.